# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n t_n = st$ if some of the limits is infinite?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given that $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = s$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} t_n = t$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n t_n = st$

provided that $st$ is defined in the extended reals.

So I know that there is a theorem that makes this true if $s$ and $t$ are finite. How do I show this for the case where either or both $s$ and $t$ are infinite?

Comment: You only have two additional cases to consider, one infinite or both infinite.

Comment: But watch out for cases $0\cdot \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

When $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\infty$ (resp. $=-\infty$) and $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=a$ with $0<a\leq\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n\>t_n)=\infty$ (resp. $=-\infty$).

Similarly, when $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\infty$  (resp. $=-\infty$) and $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=a$ with $-\infty\leq a<0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n\>t_n)=-\infty$  (resp. $=\infty$).

The difficult case is when $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n=0$. The following examples show that various outcomes are possible and that an analysis of each individual case  is necessary:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\cdot{1\over n}\right)=1,
\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2^n\cdot{1\over n}\right)=\infty,
\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n \cdot 2^{-n}\right)=0,$$
while the
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\cdot{(-1)^n\over n}\right)$$
does not exist.